# How to make toggle off when on mouse over is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover

I have created an element that is displayed when I am over a particular box.

If I move my mouse over the box I can see my element but then I need to move my mouse in and out twice for the element to disappear. How can I fix it? Shouldn't the element hide itself once I move the mouse out?

**How do I make my box only show when mouse is over the box**?

```
<script>
$("#box").on("mouseover",function()
{                  
   $("#my-box").toggle();
});
</script>
```

---

I tried to hide it myself, but it didn't work:

```
 $("#box").on("onmouseout", function()
 {
     $("#my-box").hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseout` in a same `eventlistener` like one below:

```js
$("#box").on("mouseover mouseout",function()
{                  
   $("#my-box").toggle();
});
```

```css
#my-box{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
    Box here
</div>
<div id="my-box">
    My Box
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uhgb9b1f/)**

Comment: Thank you. I like your complete example.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is you're using onmouseout instead of use mouseenter and mouseleave method.

You can use hover:

```
$('#box').hover(function(){
   $('#my-box').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of both

```
$("#box").mouseover(function() {
    $("#my-box").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $("#my-box").hide();
});
```

### [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/uhgb9b1f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery Solution

**HTML**

```
<div class="box" id="action"></div>
<div class="box" id="hidden"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#action").on("mouseover mouseout",function()
{
    $("#hidden").toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
}

#hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t08k707q/)**

Allthough it would be better doing this by just using CSS.

### CSS Only Solution

```
.box{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px;
}

#action:hover + #hidden{
    display: block;
}

#hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t08k707q/1/)**